# .Net core 2.2 not updating status code for 302 to 401. OnRedirectToLogin event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am using identityserver4 & I have following startup.cs file.

I need to return status Code 401 when 302 status code is present. But seems OnRedirectToLogin event is not firing at all (Debug point is not hitting in the event).

What's wrong or what am I missing in this code. I am using .net core 2.2.1.

It compiles successfully and also running. but response status is not changing.

```
using Clients;
using IdentityModel;
using IdentityModel.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VueCliMiddleware;

namespace sampleapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            #region Source: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Clients/src/MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh/Startup.cs

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
             {
                 options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
             })
             .AddCookie(options =>
             {
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                 options.Cookie.Name = "mvchybridautorefresh";

                 //*****Following is not working. *****
                 //*****Following is not working. *****
                 //*****Following is not working. *****
                 options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                 {
                     if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
                     {
                         context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
                         context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                     }
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                 };
                 //*****Above is not working. *****
                 //*****Above is not working. *****
                 //*****Above is not working. *****
             })
             .AddAutomaticTokenManagement()
             .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
             {
                 options.Authority = Constants.Authority;
                 options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                 options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                 options.ClientId = "mvc.hybrid.autorefresh";

                 options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                 options.Scope.Clear();
                 options.Scope.Add("openid");
                 options.Scope.Add("profile");
                 options.Scope.Add("email");
                 options.Scope.Add("api1");
                 options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                 options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("iss", "nbf", "exp", "aud", "nonce", "iat", "c_hash");

                 options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                 options.SaveTokens = true;

                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                     RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                 };

             });

            #endregion

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 360);
                    spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 8080);
                }
            });
        }

        private static bool IsAjaxRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return string.Equals(request.Query["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
                string.Equals(request.Headers["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .AddCookie(options =>
         {
             options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
             options.Cookie.Name = "mvchybridautorefresh";

              options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"); //please provide your login/logout path
              options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout");

             options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
             {
                 if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
                 {
                     context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
                     context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                 }
                 return Task.CompletedTask;
             };

         })
```

Comment: I am using identityserver. so based on ur answer I provided. "http://localhost:5000/account/login". but its still not changing response status, neither debug point is hitting there.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net core team says that it will not fire this event if oidc is used.

But I am using this oidc with cookieauthentication. So I believe it should (feature request?) fire.

Not marking as accepted answer as someone might have opinion on this.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7348#issuecomment-463888170

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
```